# Рекурсивный перебор массива в JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Подскажите пожалуйста, как перебрать массив с неизвестной вложенностью?
Ситуация такая, практикую js и reactjs на начальном уровне, делаю приложение с покемонами и хочу вывести компонент с эволюцией :).
API возвращает такой ого вида объект:

```
{
  baby_trigger_item: null,
  chain: {
    evolution_details: [],
    evolves_to: [
      {
        evolves_to: [
          {
            evolves_to: [],
            is_baby: false,
            species: {
              name: "poliwrath",
              url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/62/"
            }
          },
          {
            evolves_to: [],
            is_baby: false,
            species: {
              name: "politoed",
              url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/186/"
            }
          }
        ],
        is_baby: false,
        species: {
          name: "poliwhirl",
          url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/61/"
        }
      }
    ],
    is_baby: false,
    species: {
      name: "poliwag",
      url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/60/"
    }
  },
  id: 26
};
```

Количество вложенных массивов `"evolves_to"` может быть много, а может и не быть. а еще внутри `"evolves_to"` может быть несколько объектов, т.е развитие как бы одного уровня в несколько видов.
На выходе должно получиться(думаю такая структура будет удобна в дальнейшей работе):

```
[
    [
      {
        name: "",
        url: ""
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        name: "",
        url: ""
      },
      {
        name: "",
        url: ""
      }
    ][
      {
        name: "",
        url: ""
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Т.е первый массив с первым уровнем развития, второй массив второй уровень массива с двумя видами, третий массив соответственно третий уровень и т.д.
Если вложенность не известна, то нужно как-то оперировать с рекурсией? копал я в сторону map, reduce...и пытался влепить в них рекурсию... но к сожалению пока не додумался. Если не затруднит 'покажите пусть истинный'. Заранее благодарю )

Answer (score 1):

Здесь реализован только вывод данных, однако используя эту структуру можно легко привязать любой процесс обработки.

```
function printRec(obj, pref=''){
    let string = pref+'->'+obj.species.name; 
    console.log(string)
    if (!obj.evolves_to.length){
        return 
    }
    obj.evolves_to.forEach(elem=>printRec(elem, string))
}
printRec(a.chain)
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ! а не могли бы вы пояснить,  как он проходит 2 шаг, 3 шаг? просто хочу переделать, чтобы каждый шаг в виде объекта пушить в массив со своим ключом

Comment: Да, конечно)

У самой функции есть два сценария, либо процесс "погружения" прекратится, и процесс начнет "всплывать", либо он продолжит погружаться в граф дальше. Зависит от наличия значений в массива evolves_to.

При вызове функции передается два аргумента, obj (объект из списка) и префикс, который растет при погружении, собирая имена родителей. 

Так, если массив не пустой, мы вызываем функцию для каждого эллемента массива.

Comment: То есть, если вы хотите добавить какую-либо обработку, ее стоит добавлять вместо вывода в консоль

Comment: благодарю за пояснение) сейчас покопался, оказывается там немного другого вида будет приходящий объект, с которым нужно работать. его в вопросе я изменил. если не сложно, гляньте пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи на мой взгляд вам  подойдет такой подход, сочетание reduce, concat и немного рекурсии.

Проходясь по массиву с помощью итератора reduce, проверяется является ли текущее значение массивом, если да, то производится рекурсивный вызов функции, если нет, конкатенируем с аккумулирующим значением.

Таким образом, на входе массив неизвестной вложенности, на выходе одномерный массив.

```js
const exampleArr = [1, [1, 2, [3, 4]], [5, 6]];
const toOneLevelArray = (arr) => arr.reduce((accum, currentVal) =>  accum.concat(Array.isArray(currentVal) ? toOneLevelArray(currentVal) : currentVal), []);
console.log(toOneLevelArray(exampleArr));
```